# Add cookie to nativescript webview before page load?

Tags: webview, nativescript, session-cookies, nativescript-vue

I'm using nativescript-vue for my app development and I would like to load a special page that could skip auth page if specific cookie is set.

Is there any way I could set a specific cookie and only then load a web page using webview?

Comment: For Android you may find the [workaround here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/265),  and for [iOS refer here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5327#issuecomment-360796548)